# tableView.reloadData clears array - Index out of range

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I am receiving the error "Index out of range" when I reload my tableview.
If I comment out tableView.reloadData and print the array count it shows a full array, however when I have it in the main dispatch queue it will print an empty array and cause an error.

```
      func loadData ()  {


                posts = [CKRecord] ()
                print("loading")


                var predicate : NSPredicate!
                predicate = NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE", argumentArray: nil)
                let publicData = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
                let queryPic = CKQuery(recordType: "Main", predicate: predicate)
                publicData.perform(queryPic, inZoneWith: nil) { (results:[CKRecord]?, error:Error?) -> Void in

                    print(results?.count as Any)
            //prints full array here


                    if let Pics = results {
                       self.posts = Pics
                        DispatchQueue.main.sync{
                           //Commenting out below prints a full array 
                            self.tableView.reloadData()



                            self.refresh.endRefreshing()

                            print(results?.count as Any)
       // full array also prints here when reloadData is removed.
                            print("refreshed pics")

                        }
                    }
                    }


                }
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let varCount = posts.count as Int
        print(varCount)

        let post = posts[indexPath.row]

        let cellPic = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! StreamTableViewCell

        if let postContent = post["content"] as? String {
            let postImage = post["picture"] as? CKAsset
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: (postImage?.fileURL)!)
            let name = post["UserID"] as? String
            let vote = post["voteInteger"] as! Int

            cellPic.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
            cellPic.layer.masksToBounds = true
            cellPic.delegate = self

             cellPic.streamImageView.image = UIImage(data: data! )

            cellPic.nameLabel.text = name

            cellPic.contentLabel.text = postContent

        cellPic.voteInteger.text = String(describing: vote)

        cellPic.voteOld = vote

        cellPic.recordName = post.recordID.recordName

        }

        return cellPic
```

Here is the debugger readout-

```
loading
Optional(3)
Optional(3)
refreshed pics
3
3
loading
0
fatal error: Index out of range
2017-10-07 17:51:36.345951-0400 PondrMatchv.2[2910:357829] fatal error:
Index out of range
```

As you can see, it loads fine when the app is launched, the array contains 3 records, and does not change when reloaded.

Also, if I have only one record in the array, it will reload perfectly fine. I recently changed Cloudkit container names but even if I switch back to the old container it crashes. This also happens in the Production container as well.

Update: here is the number of rows in section function.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count   
    }
```

Also, after adding breakpoints and reconfirming with the debugger readout, it seems to be skipping over the whole dispatch call when reloading, and going straight to the tableview cellForRowAt function which is why I don't get two `Optional(3)` prints.

Comment: Move the line `self.posts = Pics` to inside the call to `DispatchQueue.main.sync`. And change `main.sync` to `main.async`.

Comment: good catch on the async, never noticed that. Still crashes with same error though @rmaddy

Comment: Did you move the `self.posts = Pics` line?

Comment: Yeah inside the dispatch call @rmaddy.

Comment: Can you post your `numberOfRowsInSection` function?

Comment: Are you sure your `numberOfRowsInSection` returns a number that's the same as your `posts.count`?

Comment: You need to post more code than that.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem by changing the predicate. Not sure if there's a bug with the swift update or what.